# How to get NSNumberFormatter currency style from ISOCurrencyCodes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter, nslocale

If I were to have EUR, or USD (both ISO currency codes), how could I make my NSNumberFormatter to properly format me a string like this?

For EUR code: 10.000,00 €
For USD code: $10,000.00

I could do this by setting localeIdentifier. But I really need to get it from the ISO currency code. Is this possible?

```
[numberFormatter stringFromNumber: [_property price]];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `setCurrencyCode:` method of `NSNumberFormatter`.

```
[numberFormatter setCurrencyCode:@"EUR"];
```

or

```
[numberFormatter setCurrencyCode:@"USD"];
```

Keep in mind that even though the desired currency symbol will be used, the resulting currency value string is still going to be formatted based on the user's locale.

Comment: That's actually what I'm trying to do. To get a string that is NOT based on user's locale, but one that is properply formatted from a currency code.

Comment: But that makes no sense. The Euro is used by people from many different locales, for example. Some want to see `1 000.00  €`, some want `1.000,00 €`, some want `€1,000.00`, etc. There is no single "proper" format for a given currency code.

Comment: Euro formatting does not change based on your location. It doesn't matter if you're in Spain, Portugal or France. This is to be integrated with a Web Service, and I need the display to be in a specific currency, regardless of a user's location. I could just give it a country with it's currency, but feels like a hammer solution. :(

Comment: You have no choice. Even USD is used in multiple locales. Personally I disagree with your assessment. I live in the USA. I want to see USD as `$10,000.00`. I also want to see EUR as `€10,000.00`. I do not want to see it as `10.000,00 €`. That's confusing to people in the USA because we use the opposite grouping and decimal symbols. Good luck with whatever you decided.

Comment: Looking for a solution for this, specially because the country where I am from has specific laws about it (here the law is that BRL is always in the format R$10.000,00 never R$10,000.00 or any variation with spaces, different groupoings and whatnot)