# How to display correct Swedish currency on IOS?

Tags: ios, locale, nslocale

I wrote the code below to display given price with a Swedish currency:

```
+(NSString *) getPriceStringWithCurrencySymbolFor:(NSNumber *)price{
    NSDictionary *components = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"sv_SE" forKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
    NSString *localeIdentifier = [NSLocale localeIdentifierFromComponents:components];
    NSLocale *localeForDefaultCurrency = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"sv_SE"];

    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [currencyFormatter setLocale:localeForDefaultCurrency];
    [currencyFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [currencyFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
    [currencyFormatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:YES];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    return [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:price];
}
```

It shows price as 75:00 kr while it should show 75,00 kr. How can I fix that?

Comment: What value are you passing for `appDelegate.shop.localeCode`?

Comment: I edited. Please check.

Comment: I can replicate it, I think this is a bug in Foundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using

```
[currencyFormatter setCurrencyCode:@"SEK"];
```

but that did not give the correct output.

Then went through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773733/how-to-get-nsnumberformatter-currency-style-from-isocurrencycodes)

A work around could be to append the string of the currency, though am not too sure whether that will fulfill your requirement.