# Function with Enumeration Parameter (and Default value)

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, ios8

I wanted to create an extension method function called toCurrencyString that has one parameter that is actually an integer enumeration of type CurrencyFormatType. The enum and code would be:

```
enum CurrencyFormatType: Int {
    /// Formats a standard currency string (localized) such as $45.35 or *45,00
    case Standard = 1,

    ///Rounded currency format (rounds up last decimals and does not return any decimals in string)
    Rounded,

    ///Will not include the thousands separator (, or .) in a string. Retains localized currency symbol.
    WithoutThousandsSeparator

}


func toCurrencyString(currencyFormat: CurrencyFormatType = 1) -> String
{
  ..my switch code w/ default to the first option if nothing passed in
}
```

I'd like to do this so that I can call .toCurrencyString on NSDecimalNumbers without having to pass in the optional parameter (most of the time I won't need it), but on the few times I do, i'd like to use an enum to select other options.

It complains at me telling me that my enum doesn't conform to IntegerLiteralConvertible. I did a little reading on how this would work but couldn't figure out the code.

Could anyone shed some light on how to get this working?

thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you considered using the built-in NSNumberFormatter?  (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773733/how-to-get-nsnumberformatter-currency-style-from-isocurrencycodes)

Comment: I'm using it in my code actually, yes! :)   This switch function then proceeds to make use of it accordingly. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, no sooner did I ask it than I figured it out. I should have waited a bit longer.
In hopes of helping others out, just a reminder about the 'Raw' aspect of enums:

Adding this to my function signature helped:

CurrencyFormatType.Raw = 1

Thanks!

alternately you could have done:

```
func toCurrencyString(currencyFormat: CurrencyFormatType = CurrencyFormatType.Standard) -> String
{
...
```